# Backpack Media Library

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using laravel backpack.
I want to open media gallery in backpack when click on browse button.
I have added file manager and the images are stored in amazon s3. The images in s3 gallery will open, when click on browse button.
Please help me, how can I open the media gallery?

I have used field type as browse. But, when I select image and trying to save it in amazon s3, it is not saving. Please help me to solve this issue.

My field:

```
    $this->crud->addField([
        'label'  => "Image",
        'name'   => "image",
        'type'   => 'browse',
        'upload' => true,
        'disk'   => 's3',
    ],
        'both');
```

My model's mutator method:

```
public function setImageAttribute($value) {
    $attribute_name = 'image'; 
    $disk = 's3'; 
    $destination_path = '';
    $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow and to Backpack. We'd be happy to help. To do so, we'll need a bit more information though. Presumably when you say " when click on browse button" you mean that you want to open the media gallery when you click on [a browse button that you've added as a field](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#browse) in one of your CRUD panels. Is that correct? If thats correct, could you please post the code for your crud controller and also let us know how that code is currently failing?

Comment: Alternatively, if you issues is that you're not sure how to set up the button to open the media manager from your CRUD, let us know that and we can help from there.

Comment: I've edited your question to include the followup question you posted in the Gitter chatroom. Based on that, it seems you worked out opening the elfinder from the browse button but cant actually upload a new image to s3. Can you please tell us if there is any error displayed on the screen or logged to your laravel log file when attempting to save fails?

Comment: Hi Wesley,
Thank you for your reply.
The file manager is opened when click on browse button and also able to select image. But, when click on save the image is not saving. In upload type, it is working fine. I have used setImageAttribute function and called uploadFileToDisk method. It is not displaying any error.

Comment: Here is the code, which I am using 
$this->crud->addField([ 
   'label' => "Image",
   'name' => "image",
   'type' => 'browse', 
                        'upload' => true,   
   'disk' => 's3',
  ], 'both');

public function setImageAttribute($value) {
  $attribute_name = 'image';  
  $disk = 's3';
  $destination_path = '';

  $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
 }

Comment: Ive edited the question to include the code you provided. Are you sure the s3 configuration is correct? Are you able to see images in the elfinder ui that are already in your s3 instance?

Comment: Also, does your model have a `protected $fillable` array property and does it contain `'image'`?

Comment: In file manager, I have already uploaded a file. Now, I am selecting the file from file manager and in browse field type it is taking input type text. So, the path is coming in input text. So, if I remove setImageAttribute method then it will save in database. So, I think input type text is not supporting. Also, there is no need to upload it again.
What do you think Wesley, is it right?